# jQuery formData | List parameter null

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, api

So, I am doing an ajax call using form data, and one of the parameters I am passing successfully reaches the API endpoint with the given value, however, the other doesn't and is always passed as null.

**The front-end part:**

```
$("#approve-registration").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var registration = { RegistrationId: $("#registrationId").val(), Applications: window.applications };
                console.log(registration);

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('Applications', registration.Applications); //This one is always passed as null
                formData.append('RegistrationId', registration.RegistrationId);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/registration/approve",
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (result != null) {
                            alert("Registration " + result.RegistrationId + " saved sucessfully!");
                            //location.href = '/registration/index';
                        } else {
                            alert("Something went wrong!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

The content of *registration* is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIVrG.jpg

The arguments that are passed to the API endpoint:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgA2Q.jpg

The structure of a RegistrationApproveModel:

```
public class RegistrationApproveModel
{
    public string RegistrationId { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationModel> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

The structure of an ApplicationModel:

```
public class ApplicationModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SettingModel> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

The structure of a SettingModel:

```
public class SettingModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Do you have a hint why Applications is being passed as null?
Let me emphasize that the other parameter (RegistrationId) has value.

Comment: please try set ajax-property `dataType: "json",`

Comment: Ty, but it hasn't worked. Let me emphasize that I am able to pass a value in one of the arguments (RegistrationId) but not on the other (Applications)

Comment: yes but the difference is that one property is just a string and the other is a js-object. you could try to stringify it `formData.append('Applications', JSON.stringify(registration.Applications))` and on the server serialize it

Comment: I have not coded the serialization part on the back-end API, but at least adding the stringify on the front-end hasn't helped, since the argument is still reaching the endpoint with null.